# Refresh Oauth token after certain time in Node API

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, refresh-token

I have exposed a REST api built on Express to Client but my api is invoking external API which requires rotational oauth token every 60 minutes and I am not expecting token from client,I have to generate it my own before calling external api on every 60 minutes and pass it to external api.I am using following code using setTimeOut function
But I am looking any other better approach to refresh the token behind the seen.Please help me

```
//Refresh Token logic

     async refreshToken() {
            try {
                let token = 'xyz-sbdkd'//from api;
                // set token in global variable
                process.env.TOKEN = token

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.refreshToken();
                }, 59 * 60000);//this will be 59 minutes
            } catch (err) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.refreshToken();
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal approach is to handle the 401 `Unauthorized` Error, that is used when the token is expired.

```
  let axiosRequest = async (options) => {
    try {
      await axios(options) // try to call
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.status === 401) { // token is expired
        let accessToken = await getNewAccessToken(refreshToken) // call the refresh token endpoint to get a new access token
        options.headers = {Authorization : `Bearer ${accessToken}`} // set the new access token to initial petition
        return await axiosRequest(options) // call again with new token
      }
      throw err
    }
  }
```

A more elegant approach can be found using the axios native interceptors, but couldnt try it:
https://gist.github.com/mkjiau/650013a99c341c9f23ca00ccb213db1c